# Prove that operator is completely continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let's consider Banach space $\ell^\infty$ of bounded sequences $x = \{ \xi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$:
$$
||x|| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} |\xi_n|.
$$
Suppose matrix $||a_{i j}||_1^\infty$ specifies operator $A$ in $\ell^\infty$ such that vector $x = (\xi_1, \xi_2, \dots)$ transforms into vector $y = Ax = (\eta_1, \eta_2, \dots)$, where
$$
\eta_i = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_{i j} \xi_j.
$$
How to prove operator $A$ is completely continuous if it's matrix is nonnegative and has finite row-wise sums:
$$
a_{i \star} = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_{i j} < \infty \, ?
$$
If necessary we can suppose sequence $\{a_{i \star}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of row-wise sums is bounded. We can also suppose the matrix of $A$ is irreducible, or in other words some power of $A$ is strictly positive.

Comment: $\ell^\infty$ is not a Hilbert space. You probably meant to write "Banach space".

Comment: Ok, right. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: The boundedness of $a_{i\star}$ is absolutely necessary, without that, $A$ doesn't even map $\ell^\infty$ to itself.

Comment: @DanielFischer, indeed. By the way, is it possible to define an innerproduct $(x, y)$ such that $\sqrt{(x,x)} = ||x||$ in this case?

Comment: And even then, we need stronger conditions on $A$. Consider $a_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker $\delta$). Then $A$ is the identity, and that is not completely continuous.

Comment: No. The norm doesn't satisfy the parallelogram identity. Furthermore, $\ell^\infty$ is not reflexive, hence its topology cannot be induced by a norm arising from an inner product.

Comment: @DanielFischer, ok, let's say the matrix is irreducible, or in other words some power of $A$ is positive.

Comment: Can you prove that the operator is compact?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, I thought completely continuous means compact, no? I think I can show it if $\lim_{i \to \infty} a_{i \star} = 0$, but that's not the case.

Comment: @Wormer: But this is not the case. So what ideas do you have to tackle the problem?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, if we could show a sequence of compact operators is converging in operator norm to $A$ then it will be the deal. But I don't know which sequence to use. Also I'm starting to doubt $A$ is compact at all...

Comment: For instance, if we put $a_{i j} = \delta_{i j} + e^{-i^2 - j^2}$, then will this operator be compact?

Comment: @Wormer It won't. The operator given by $a_{ij} = e^{-i^2-j^2}$ is compact, so that one plus the identity can't be compact.